# Godot jump animation starting after a slight delay from the input

Tags: 2d-games, godot

this is one of my first projects and i'm writing this code following a tutorial on YT. This tutorial does not include stuff about animation as far as i've seen, so i tried getting it done myself and the idle and run animations work. The jump also works but it starts after a slight delay and doesn't complete its cycle because the character lands too soon (for this last problem i'll try adjusting the speed of the animation)

extends Actor

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = get_direction()
    velocity = calculate_move_velocity(velocity, direction, maxSpeed)
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL) #Funzione che permette il movimento del personaggio
func get_direction() -> Vector2:
    return Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left"),
        -1.0 if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor() else 0.0
    )

func calculate_move_velocity(               #Movimento e Animazioni
        linear_velocity: Vector2,
        direction: Vector2,
        maxSpeed: Vector2
    ) -> Vector2:
    var new_velocity = linear_velocity      #la new_velocity sarà il movimento lineare del personaggio
    new_velocity.x = maxSpeed.x * direction.x
    new_velocity.x = lerp(new_velocity.x, 0, 0.1)
    if is_on_floor() and direction.x == 1.0:                  #muoversi verso destra
        $AnimationPlayer.play("run")
        $Sprite.scale.x = 1
    elif is_on_floor() and direction.x == -1.0:               #muoversi verso sinistra
        $AnimationPlayer.play("run")
        $Sprite.scale.x = -1
    if is_on_floor() and direction.x == 0.0:                  #stare fermi
        $AnimationPlayer.play("idle")
    new_velocity.y += gravity * get_physics_process_delta_time()
    if direction.y == -1.0:                 #saltare
        new_velocity.y = maxSpeed.y * direction.y
    if !is_on_floor() == false and Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        $AnimationPlayer.play("jump")
    return new_velocity
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of little things, will go over them one by one.

---

**Is on floor?**

The value `is_on_floor()` is updated when you call `move_and_slide(...)`. But you are calling `is_on_floor()` before calling `move_and_slide(...)`, which means it is operating the value of the prior physics frame. In fact, you want `move_and_slide(...)` to hit the ground (and thus, you probably want to apply gravity first).

This by it self is not a big deal. *It is mostly noticeable for frame perfect jump, but still.*

---

**Lerp?**

I'm looking at this line:

```
new_velocity.x = lerp(new_velocity.x, 0, 0.1)
```

Let us see the official documentation for [`lerp`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html?#class-gdscript-method-lerp). It says the signature of `lerp` is:

```
Variant lerp ( Variant from, Variant to, float weight )
```

So we are interpolating from `new_velocity.x` to `0` with a weight of `0.1`. I believe that is the same as:

```
new_velocity.x *= 0.9
```

Considering that other line also:

```
new_velocity.x = maxSpeed.x * direction.x
new_velocity.x = lerp(new_velocity.x, 0, 0.1)
```

We have:

```
new_velocity.x = maxSpeed.x * direction.x * 0.9
```

And considering that `direction.x` goes from `-1` to `1`, we have that `new_velocity.x` never reaches `maxSpeed.x`.

*Why you want to do that? What do you think you are accomplishing?*

---

**Scale sprite?**

You use `$Sprite.scale.x = 1` and `$Sprite.scale.x = -1`. Sprites have a [`flip_h`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_sprite.html#class-sprite-property-flip-h) property strongly encouraged for this use.

---

**Double negative?**

You have this little nugget of code: `!is_on_floor() == false`.

Let us make a truth table:

```
is_on_floor() │ !is_on_floor() │ !is_on_floor() == false
──────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────
 false        │ true           │ false
 true         │ false          │ true
```

As you can see, `!is_on_floor() == false` is the same as `is_on_floor()`. *By the way, it returns `bool`, not `Variant`, in case that is your concern.*

---

**Playing animation multiple times**

As you must be aware, calling [`AnimationPlayer.play`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animationplayer.html#class-animationplayer-method-play) multiple times with the same animation, is no problem at all. Which also means you don't need to check if the jump action was *just* pressed.

---

**Separation of concerns**

On one hand we have the concern of moving the kinematic body. On the other we have the concern of playing the animations. The first concern is a physics concern. It make sense to do it in `_physics_process`. The second concern is a visual concern. It makes sense to do it in `_process` instead.

---

**Bringing it all together.**

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
    var h_direction = Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left")
    velocity.x = maxSpeed.x * h_direction
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = -maxSpeed.y

func _process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if is_on_floor():
        if velocity.x == 0.0:
            $AnimationPlayer.play("idle")
            $Sprite.flip_h = false
        else:
            $AnimationPlayer.play("run")
            $Sprite.flip_h = velocity.x < 0.0
     else:
         $AnimationPlayer.play("jump")
```

*Short and sweet.*

**Note**: I replaced `FLOOR_NORMAL` with [`Vector2.UP`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html#constants). Also I removed the `0.9` introduced by `lerp`. Otherwise this should be the same, minus `is_on_floor` and animation play timing issues (I think this also differs on walls, there is [`is_on_wall()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html#class-kinematicbody2d-method-is-on-wall) if that is an issue). However, we are talking of issues that at most expand one physics frame.

---

**One more thing**

Given that you are working with sprites in 2D. Consider using [`AnimatedSprite`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite.html) for the sprite animations instead of `AnimationPlayer`.

By the way, the timing of the animation may be the causing an apparent delay. For example if the first sprite of the jump animation matches - say - a frame of the idle animation. That is one whole frame that has to pass before we see a jump sprite. Double check that.

Comment: Thank you! It will take me quite a bit to digest and understand everything that you wrote, but i'm seriously glad you decided to explain so much to a newbie! I hope i'll be able to understand as much as possible from your explanation and learn to write cleaner and more efficient code.

Comment: Alright @Theraot , took me less than expected to comprehend and change most of the problems my code had (less than half an hour when i started working on it). The only thing i still haven't understood is the is_on_floor( ) before move_and_slide( . . . ) part. I just took `velocity = calculate_move_velocity(velocity, direction, maxSpeed)` and put it after `velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL)`, is that what i'm supposed to do?

Comment: @BlindVI the value of `is_on_floor` is updated in `move_and_slide`. Using `is_on_floor` before `move_and_slide` gives you the value from the prior physics frame. If you have 60 physics frames per second (which is the default, see project settings), it is a possible delay of 0.016 seconds in jump response, when the value `is_on_floor` should have changed but didn't (i.e. when the player wants to jump the same physics frame the avatar landed). Admittedly it is hard to notice, but matters for tight controls. It is an occasional "I pressed it, it didn't jump" issue on consecutive jumps.

Comment: @BlindVI We can do better than that, of course, with input buffering and cayote time and so on. However, just changing the order of those instruction is too easy not to do.

Comment: oh, uh.. i don't know what input buffering and cayote time are lol

Comment: @BlindVI Input buffering means storing the input for a while. In this case, if the player pressed jump, we store the time. And when the player is on the floor we check if the time jump was pressed was *recently*. Allowing the player to hit jump just before the avatar lands and still register. Cayote time is similar but for checking the floor, so that the game allows jumping if the avatar was on the floor *recently*. So that it can jump even if the player already stepped out of a platform. *You know, like Wile E. Coyote running on the air*. These improve game feel, but aren't the issue here.

Comment: ok i didn't quite get that, but since i'm just starting out i think that's normal. I'll try searching more information around about this

Comment: @BlindVI see [Improve Your Game Feel With Coyote Time and Jump Buffering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97_jvSPoRDo). You might also be interested in [Why Does Celeste Feel So Good to Play?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yorTG9at90g).

Comment: Thank you, i'll make sure to check out these resources!